# Send music control keys from my app in android

Tags: android

Is there a simple way to tell the default media player to change track back or forward?

I want the ability to send commands to the system media player (Music) to change track back and forward from within my app.

Is there a simple way? Code examples or descriptive explanation please, I have not developed for Android before.

Update: Is it just the HTC Music that isn't part of the SDK or even the stock one? Either player would be fine if I could manage  way to change tracks.

The HTC Lock screen has some method of changing tracks in the music player. Is it possible I could get hold of this and use it?

Baksmali?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want the ability to send commands to
>   the system media player (Music) to
>   change track back and forward from
>   within my app.

The Music application is not part of the Android SDK, so there are no documented and supported `Intents` for moving from track to track.

Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

by ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON using intent ??
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON

```
    Intent media_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    media_intent.setPackage(DEFAULTPLAYER);
    synchronized (this) {
        media_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, keycode));
        mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(media_intent, null);

        media_intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, keycode));
        mContext.sendOrderedBroadcast(media_intent, null);
    }
```

however DEFAULTPLAYER needs to be assigned...

:S :S :S